# What is the best way to display comments in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, html, web, repeater, datarepeater

I'm developing a social network using Microsoft Technologies. I want to make a Wall similar to the one in Facebbok. What is the best way to do it and display comments ? Repeaters ? I'm using classic ASP.NET not MVC

Comment: Are you using MVC or Classic ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Are you going to use Restful state or something else.

I personally use the repeater has you have more control over the HTML, Jquery etc that is being displayed.

AJAX toolkit in VS could give you the update panel to display items.

The easiest to develop and maintain is normally my approach, but everyone will have their preferences.

Answer (score 0):

If you use 3.5 try ListView control which has new cool features comparing to Repeater.

Comment: True, but if you have to be concerned with javascript being used for some of the features, or you need properly formed XHTML, not all the built in tools generate the expected HTML output.